# Java 9 ifPresentOrElse returning value

Tags: java, lambda, option-type, java-9

1/ Working code:

```
public Student process (int id, name){
  Optional<Student> studentOpt = myrepo.findById(id);
  studentOpt.isPresent() {
    return updateStudent(id, name);
  } else {
   return createStudent(id, name);
  }
```

2/ I try to change it to 'full lambdas code' (not working):

```
public Student process (int id, name){
  Optional<Student> studentOpt = myrepo.findById(id);
  return studentOpt.ifPresentOrElse(student-> return updateStudent(id, name), () ->  return createStudent(id, name));
}
```

1/ should I change it to full lambda? what is the cleanest?

2/ if yes, how ?

Comment: And what exactly does "not working" mean? Please see the [ask] article for help on building a question we can actually answer :)

Comment: Remove the `return` calls from inside the call to `ifPresentOrElse`, and it should work.  You might have to make `id` and `name` effectively final.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Given that your methods `updateStudent` and `createStudent` involve some form of side effect and you should generally prefer side effect free lambdas, I don't recommend you use them here. In fact, a simple if-then-else block would be sufficient. However, if you are curious, the equivalent lambda would look like:

```
return studentOpt
    .map(unused -> updateStudent(id, name))
    .orElseGet(() -> createStudent(id, name));
```

Comment: flawless answer @Ravindra

Comment: THANK YOU! Been searching for hours. I miss Java 6